# VBA comma separated cells, needt last entry only

Tags: excel, vba

So i have a data set which has the city and address in the same cell, I want to remove the city, which is usually the last comma separated value, and put it into a cell next to it
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57PtQ.png)

Comment: you may use split function, http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-split-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your image but after your explanation, you are looking for the following function:

```
Function Remove_last_part(StrCommaSeparated As String) As String

    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    arr = Split(StrCommaSeparated, ",") ' make an array out of the comma separated string

    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1) ' Remove the last array element, by redimensioning the array to it's total elements minus 1

    Remove_last_part = Join(arr, ",")  ' make a comma separated string out of the redimensionned array

End Function
```

Example on how to use it :

```
Public Sub TestIt()

    Dim strTest As String

    strTest = "anything,anywhen,anyhow,New York"

    Debug.Print "BEFORE -->" & strTest
    Debug.Print "AFTER  -->" & Remove_last_part(strTest)

End Sub
```

Will output :

> ```
> BEFORE -->anything,anywhen,anyhow,New York
> AFTER  -->anything,anywhen,anyhow
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Apologies for my somewhat basic question!